# changed behavior for grails.views.default.codec = "html" in grails 2.0?

Tags: grails, encoding

We used something like in the example below before:

```
class KontrollController {
    def index() { 
        [ value: "hä öh üh!"]
    }
}
```

calling the Tag like this:

```
<pl:myTag value="${value}">${value}</pl:myTag>
```

Taglib:

```
class PlTagLib {
    static namespace = "pl"

    def myTag = { attrs, body ->
            def m = [:]
            log.error body()
            m.body = body()
            m.value = attrs.value

            out << render( template: '/template/myTag', model: m )
        }
}
```

in _myTag.gsp

```
 ${body} //will display: "h&auml; &ouml;h &uuml;h!" wrong encoding
 ${value} // will display correct: "hä öh üh!"
```

we uses this version with body many times before and it worked correct.

can anyone tell me if there is a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is blind shot but you can try:

```
class KontrollController {
    def index() { 
        [ value: "hä öh üh!".encodeAsHTML()]
    }
}
```